# in python2.6/logging/handlers.py in shouldRollover due to non-posix-compliant Windows feature

Tags: python

I'm facing a strange issue with this in python.
i googled it but did not find any good feedback

When my run my script it seems that it crashes at the end of the execution
for an unknow reason. Here is the message :

```
python2.6/logging/handlers.py, line 146, in shouldRollover due to non-posix-
compliant Windows feature AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 
'seek'
```

I'm sure that my code executed completely before, even if some exception was raised, i catch them all to log their details and the above message always appears after my ones. It seems that there is a problem in the closing of the python process itself.

I assume my usage of logs is almost normal, i use several logs in several scripts and subscripts but with a different name and filename each time...

If anyone has an idea i would be glad to know

Thanks and regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the root cause so i post here:

Actually my python was using multi-threading (threading.thread) and some logging was made from inside of one of the other threads, making access to 1 single file from several threads. This is actually supported by python, but my mistake was that nowhere in my code i was "joining" all the threads to the main one. 
This is what was causing some concurrent "close" operation on the log files.
Calling the join function fixed these messages.

Regards